# 404 not found error on php website (namecheap)

Tags: php, .htaccess, namecheap

I have just deployed a new php website I created on namecheap. When I visit the website homepage, it works fine, but when I try to access other pages, I get a 404 page not found error as seen in the image below.
[image]

I have the following code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My index.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/_core/config/init.php';
$query_string = 'url';
$_GET[$query_string] = isset($_GET[$query_string]) && !empty($_GET[$query_string]) ? $_GET[$query_string] : "home";

$url_array = explode("/", $_GET[$query_string]);

foreach ($url_array as $key => $value) {
    $url_array[$key] = preg_replace('/.php/', "", $url_array[$key]);
}

$_page = isset($url_array[0]) && !empty($url_array[0]) ? $url_array[0] : "index";
$_section = isset($url_array[1]) && !empty($url_array[1]) ? $url_array[1] : "index";

$url_array_count = count($url_array);

if ($url_array_count >= 3) {
    //error page
    include_once __DIR__ . "/assets/shared/404.php";
}


if (in_array($_page, getPages())){    
    include_once(__DIR__ . '/includes/components/head.php');
    include_once(__DIR__ . '/includes/pages/' . $_page . '.php');
    die();
}

$isLogin = isset($_SESSION['app_session']['cms']['is_login']) ? $_SESSION['app_session']['cms']['is_login'] : false;

if($_page == 'controls'){
    $cmsPg = getCMSPgName()[0]['sccPage'];   
    if($isLogin ){    
        include_once(__DIR__ . '/includes/cmspages/'.$_page.'.php');
        die();
    }else{
        include_once(__DIR__ . '/includes/cmspages/cmslogin.php');
        die();
    }
}else{
    if($isLogin ){             
        include_once(__DIR__ . '/includes/cmspages/'.$_page.'.php');
        die();
    }else{
        include_once(__DIR__ . '/includes/cmspages/cmslogin.php');
        die();
    }
}  include_once(__DIR__ . '/includes/cmspages/contentmgr.php');
```

Please, help with solution. Is there some configuration I'm missing on the live server?

Comment: I don’t understand the purpose of the first two rewrite rules.

Comment: Also, instead of the older “check for a file or directory, then jam everything into the query string”, modern Apache has [`FallbackResource`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/231316) along with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Does a file called `aboutus.php` (which is where the first rule would point to) even exist?

Comment: All files exist. And everything works just fine on my local machine.

Comment: So, a file called `aboutus.php` really exists? Why did you share the code from `index.php`?

Comment: I control traffic in the index.php file. I noticed that the .htaccess file is not being read at all. I wrote some random text in the .htaccess file, expecting a 500 server error but there was no 500 server error, this tells me the .htaccess file is not being read at all. This indicates that there's some configuration I need to do on the server (maybe apache related) which I don't know. Any ideas, please?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Maybe you aren't using Apache after all?